# Can't get Jedi's autocompletion on SuperTab

Tags: vim, autocomplete, supertab, python-jedi

I installed both plugins using Pathogen, but they don't work together as it should be. That is, if I use TAB, I get SuperTab's completion (autocomplete what I have previously written) whereas if I use CTRL + SPACE I get Jedi's completion (everything from libs: classes, modules, etc).

In theory, if both plugins are installed SuperTab should handle Jedi seamlessly, but that's not my case. I found [this report](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/issues/165) of some people experiencing the same behavior, while others saying it works for them. There is no solution provided though.

The plugins I'm using don't override each other:

```
ls ~/.vim/bundle/
auto-pairs  nerdtree  syntastic    vim-trailing-whitespace
jedi-vim    supertab  vim-airline
```

So what else may be causing this behavior?

vimrc:

```
set nu
set ts=4
set sw=4
set mouse=a
set showmatch
set expandtab
set background=dark
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on

execute pathogen#infect()

set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*

let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
```

Comment: I have the exact same setup and it works for me. Maybe you want to look at it: https://github.com/davidhalter/dotfiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the root of the problem. SuperTab wasn't working in OmniCompletion mode.

`let g:SuperTabContextDefaultCompletionType = "<c-x><c-o>"`

Comment: I tried this but my supertab stil does not autocomplete with jedi's autocompletion. Any idea?